# Kernel of a power of an endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is a vector space of dimension $n$ and $f: V \rightarrow V$ a linear map. If $\operatorname{dim ker}(f) = 1$, is it true that $f^{n-1}$ is nonzero? And if so, how do I see that? I tried proving that $\operatorname{dim ker}(f^i) = i$, but didn't succeed.

Comment: You don't have $\dim \ker f^i = i$ in general, but $\dim \ker f^i \leqslant i$.

Comment: Your formula is false. If $f$ is a projection on a $n-1$-dimensional subspace, $f^i=f$. Try another trick.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that. I have $\operatorname{ker} (f^i) = \operatorname{ker} (f^{i-1}) \cup (f^{i})^{-1}(\operatorname{ker} (f))$, I was hoping to be able to prove something inductively.

Comment: Okay, the above equation doesn't get me anywhere. @DanielFischer This inequality $\dim \ker f^i \leqslant i$ would be enough to show that $f^{n-1} \neq 0$, but how could I prove it?

Comment: Inductively. At each step, either $\operatorname{im} f^i \cap \ker f = \{0\}$, or $\ker f \subset \operatorname{im} f^i$. Thus either $\operatorname{rank} f^{i+1} = \operatorname{rank} f^i$, or $\operatorname{rank} f^{i+1} = \operatorname{rank} f^i - 1$.